# How to I use set method with stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

Hello I have a these field in db:

```
String abcTitlename;
 String abcTitlepage;
```

And I want to get these field from entity, But I want to use without 'abc' prefix. Example

my field is abcTittlename name but I want to get this tittlename.

Could I get these field with filter? Could I do this using replaceAll method? like this:

```
stream = stream.map(e -> ((DbFields)e).setFieldname(((DbFields) e).getFieldname().replace("abc","")))
                        .filter(e -> ((DbFields) e).getIscomputed().equals(0));

        return stream.map(e -> ((DbFields) e).getFieldname().toLowerCase(Locale.US)).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    }
```

And I have DbFields class , that has getFieldName(),getFieldtype() vs methods.

I get an

```
Error:(170, 29) java: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
    upper bounds: java.lang.Object
    lower bounds: void
```

error. What am I doing wrong?
Help me,please..

Comment: map() expects a Function. A Function<A, B> is something that transforms something (an A) into something else (a B), and returns the transformed value (the B). Not something that mutates its argument, returning void.

Comment: Streams are meant to be side-effect free, so the best answer is: don’t.

Answer (score 0):

return the object after you manipulate it

```
stream = stream.map(e -> {
             ((DbFields)e).setFieldname(((DbFields) e).getFieldname().replace("abc",""));
             return e;
         })
         ...
```

Comment: stream = stream.map(e -> {
                ((DbFields)e).setFieldname(((DbFields) e).getFieldname().replace("abc",""));
                return e;
        }).filter(a -> ((SysFields) a)).getIscomputed().equals(0);


I get an 

Error:(172, 25) java: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
    systems.hotech.otello.orest.model.sysdefs.SysFields cannot be converted to boolean @Michal

Answer (score 0):

You may want to replace .map with .peek as you are not mapping to a different object. You are just updating the same object.

And in the second map call, you are not updating field name.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a separate `map` call with just the typecasting in the beginning, so your code won't get polluted with all these casts.

Here's the example, rewritten with the suggested `peek` method

```
return stream.map(e -> (DbFields)e)
      .filter(e -> e.getIscomputed().equals(0))
      .peek(e -> e.setFieldname(e.getFieldname().replace("abc", "")))
      .map(e -> e.getFieldname().toLowerCase(Locale.US))
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```